# Is it possible to connect using the CosmosDB connector to Table Storage?

Tags: python, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, databricks, azure-table-storage

I'm uploading data to Table Storage, but I need to use the CosmosDB connector to be able to do a full insert of a large Spark Dataframe to my Table Storage table, as I don't want to use TableClient because this causes concurrency issues.

My current code is the following:

```
from azure.data.tables import TableClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

# credentials
client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret = "yyyyyyyyyyy"
tenant_id = "zzzzzzzzzzzz"

# URL
table_url = "https://accountExample.table.core.windows.net"

# Table Name
table_name = "myTable"

token_credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id,
    client_id,
    client_secret,
)
# Client
table_client = TableClient(endpoint=table_url, credential=token_credential, table_name=table_name)
```

And im trying to do something like this, but I don't find anything similar to above to connect cosmosDB to Table Storage like above:

```
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient
from azure.mgmt.cosmosdb import CosmosDBManagementClient

credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)

client = CosmosDBManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
```

It is worth mentioning that I cannot use the Account_key, I can only use the client_id and client_secret for security reasons for authentication.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The CosmosDB Client does not work with Table Storage since it is meant for the NoSQL API of CosmosDB.

But to help with your issue, you could consider using [Azure CosmosDB for Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/introduction) which basically gives you the power of CosmosDB with the same API as Azure Storage Tables.